# Is there a flaw in this proof of Marty's theorem (normal families)?

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

In Ahlfors' Complex Analysis text, page 227 the author claims that if the expression $$\rho(f)=\frac{2 |f'(z)|}{1+|f(z)|^2}$$ is locally bounded (here $f \in \mathfrak F$ is a family of meromorphic functions in some domain $\Omega$), then the family $\mathfrak F$ is equicontinuous (with respect to the spherical metric) on compact subsets of $\Omega$.

In particular, he states that

> If $\rho(f) \leq M$ on the line segment between $z_1$ and $z_2$ we conclude that $d(f(z_1),f(z_2)) \leq M|z_1- z_2|$, and this immediately proves the equicontinuity when $\rho(f)$ is locally bounded.

I believe that he intended that we start the formula for the length

$$L=\int_\gamma \rho(f) |dz| $$
where $\gamma$ is the line segment between $z_1$ and $z_2$, and apply the triangle inequality.

My problem with this proof is that $f$ might not even be defined on that line segment (if $\Omega$ is not convex), and in that case the integral formula is invalid.

Is this proof correct after all? If so, what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct, but curt. Some things remain implicit.

The integral estimate gives you for every $z \in K \subset \Omega$ a Lipschitz constant on a small disk around $z$. Since $K$ is compact, you can cover it by finitely many such disks. For small enough $\delta_0 > 0$, for any two points $z,w$ in $K$ with $\lvert z - w\rvert \leqslant \delta_0$, there is one disk containing both, and hence the segment connecting the two points. So for equicontinuity ($(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\dotsc)$), choose the $\delta$ always smaller than $\delta_0$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have some difficulty with finding such $\delta_0$:
If for example $K$ is the union of two tangent balls there exist pairs of points, each from different ball, which get arbitrarily close to each other.

Comment: The disks are supposed to be open. (I leave some things implicit, too, it seems ;) Every open cover of a compact metric space has a [Lebesgue number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) that is larger than $0$.